# Alternative ways to receive result from async/await on Main Thread for Swift

Tags: swift, swiftui, async-await, uikit, grand-central-dispatch

Recently, I ran into a problem where I got a warning for updating UI on background task.

```
func didInit() async {
    listOfTodo = await interactor.getTodos()
}
```

I tried to wrap the function body inside DispatchQue.main.async {}, but I got an error.

I then found a solution which I have to put @MainActor on top of my function, but I feel like there are other solutions that would make more sense, or this is the only way to work with async/await on Main Thread?

```
@MainActor
func didInit() async {
    listOfTodo = await interactor.getTodos()
}
```

Comment: Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot. You have to update UI on the `MainActor` but everything else can be done on other actors or `detached`

Comment: @loremipsum thanks for replying. I tho I already provided MRE because that's the only code which I used. basically I wanna do the listOfTodo = await interactor.getTodos() on a main thread, but I could not do with DispatchQue since it returned an error.

Comment: That is not an MRE but `DispatchQueue` and `async await` are incompatible. If that is your goal with this question it will never work. `async await` is meant to completely replace all the `Dispatch` options.

Comment: Marking the method with `@MainActor` is a good way to do this. If, however, you're doing this in a type that has lots of methods/properties that need to be updated on the main actor, often you would add `@MainActor` on the whole type, saving you from having to decorate each function individually. E.g., we often decorate our view models with `@MainActor`, for example, as we invariably want all the view model updates to be published back to the view on the main actor.

Comment: did you mean to tag this as SwiftUI? If so, simply put it in a `.task`

Answer (score 3):

You're approaching this backwards. If `interactor.getTodos()` must be run on the main actor, then *it* should be marked `@MainActor`, not the caller. But if `didInit` is logically "a UI-updating method," then it's fine to mark it `@MainActor` as well.

Or you can use `MainActor.run {...}` to manually move this one call to the main actor. It all comes down to what you mean to express.

Comment: I appreciate you took your time and answered in a genuine way, but I still have one problem which is MainActor.run{...} does not work with async function(), so instead I tried another way like this: Task { @MainActor in
            listOfTodo = await interactor.getTodos()
        }.

Comment: yes, that's the correct way to get an async context inside of `run`.

Answer (score 1):

A better approach would be to create a function which takes responsibility of updating UI, something like below

```
@MainActor
func updateUI() async {
    // Code to update your UI
}
```

Call this function inside your task function like below

```
func didInit() {
        Task.detached {                          // or specify a priority with Task.detached(priority: .background)
        listOfTodo = interactor.getTodos()
        await self.updateUI()
    }
}
```

Note: Code is not tested on Xcode so may be require some changes

Comment: This is an interesting decoupled approach